# How to run daily cron job on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I've written a shellscript (.sh) and put it here (I did also a `chmod +x` on the script):

```
/etc/cron.daily/
```

Do I have to do something more to let this work?
Because I saw:

```
May 28 05:32:50 ip-172-31-xx-xx dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.xx.xx on eth0 to 172.31.xx.1 port 67 (xid=0x7340709e)
May 28 05:32:50 ip-172-31-xx-xx dhclient: DHCPACK of 172.31.xx.xx from 172.31.16.1
May 28 05:32:50 ip-172-31-xx-xx dhclient: bound to 172.31.xx.xx -- renewal in 1607 seconds.
May 28 05:59:37 ip-172-31-xx-xx dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.xx.xx on eth0 to 172.31.xx.xx port 67 (xid=0x7340709e)
May 28 05:59:37 ip-172-31-xx-xx dhclient: DHCPACK of 172.31.xx.xx from 172.31.xx.xx
May 28 05:59:37 ip-172-31-xx-xx dhclient: bound to 172.31.xx.xx -- renewal in 1702 seconds.
May 28 06:17:01 ip-172-31-xx-xx CRON[17051]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 28 06:25:01 ip-172-31-xx-xx CRON[18496]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
```

But my job didn't run (it writes .tar's to S3 and didn't saw it)

**EDIT 1**

`35 7    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )` is the content of the `/etc/crontab`

So if the execution of `/usr/sbin/anacron` works, it will not execute my `cron.daily`. So if I delete `/usr/sbin/anacron`, it will only execute my `/etc/cron.daily` and than it works.
But why is `/usr/sbin/anacron` there? I don't find the `anacron` in my files. Can I just delete this in my `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: What is your script's name? Does it end in `.sh`?

Comment: yes it ends with the extension .sh

Comment: That might be your problem, from the [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) page: " Although the directories contain periods in their names, run-parts will not accept a file name containing a period and will fail silently when encountering them (bug #38022). Either rename the file or use a symlink (without a period) to it instead...". See whether it works when you rename the file `myscript` rather than `myscript.sh`. If it does, I will post it in the answer and you can accept it.

Comment: Can test it tomorrow. Will let you know